# Java: Where is the method?

Tags: java, class, methods, call, superclass

I just try to understand some code of an api, by reading the source. Here is a link:

https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/MemorySection.java

In this class you can find the method `public int getInt(String path, int def)`. This method calls `toInt(val)`. Where can I find this method. As there is no object or class specified such as `anObject.toInt(val)` or `ClassName.toInt(val)` the method must be defined in that class or in a superclass, but I cant find it.

My questions: Is that the original source? Can you find it? Where is it?

Comment: This is one very good reason to use a modern IDE. They allow you to "click through" method calls, saving you the hassle of finding out where they are defined. (You should still understand what static imports are and how they work, but when there are 15 static imports in a file, you really don't want to trawl through each of them to find your method.)

Comment: Although if you've got 15 wildcard static imports in a file, it's probably time to rethink. :)

Comment: @biziclop I didn't even heard about static imports up to now. I learned myself java, and I always try to understand what I do. And now I also understand how static imports work. I wont use them anyway. Thanks to all who answered my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toInt()` method comes from the class `org.bukkit.util.NumberConversions`.

Now, why isn't the class specified and how can this work ? If you look at the imports at the top of the file, you will see this :

```
import static org.bukkit.util.NumberConversions.*;
```

This basically means

> Make available to me any public static method in in the `org.bukkit.util.NumberConversions` class.

This is a useful feature of Java when you want to make your code more concise. However, since the class responsible for this method is not immediately obvious, it is better to use it only for widely-user helper methods, such as `toInt` here.

Another typical example are the JUnit assertions. It is even explained [in their javadoc](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html) :

> These methods can be used directly: Assert.assertEquals(...), however, they read better if they are referenced through static import:
>
> ```
> import static org.junit.Assert.*;
>    ...
>     assertEquals(...);
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can find an import statement with static in the first line of the java file(which is nothing but the static import, imports only the methods of the class).

```
import static org.bukkit.util.NumberConversions.*;
```

You can find the method in this [link](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/util/NumberConversions.java). Just traverse to the class and search.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about static imports.

Comment: And that is why wildcard imports are BS and need to be avoided.

Comment: @Tom "Used judiciously" is probably a more appropriate phrase. They have their use, but it's very limited.

Comment: @biziclop And which use should that be?

Comment: @Tom Importing all the values of an enum for example. Or the `Assert.*` case given above.

Comment: @biziclop If I need to import each single enum value in a different class, then I may have a different problem. For example a "smelly" `switch` statement for these enum values. And about the `Assert` recommendation: one can still use wildcard imports even though they have a very limited value. But, well, they have one advantage: they indicate other (structural) problems, like overused static code like `if/else` and `switch` or if someone tries to shrink his code at the wrong position.

Comment: You may or you may not. It isn't as cut and dry as you'd like to see it, very few things are. I personally prefer not to use static import but I can see valid uses for it, where it actually improves readability of the code.

Comment: @biziclop Where are not talking about static imports ;P.